# Adding margins within a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my application, I am using fragments. The problem is I am not able to set margin for each item in the list inside `TitlesFragment extends ListFragment`. Also I have to add margin to my complete set of data shown inside `DetailsFragment extends Fragment`. How can this be done? Please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Please see my xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/bg"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_view"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="10dp"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `divider` and the `dividerHeight` properties in your `layout.xml` file.
For instance

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
  android:dividerHeight="5dip" />
```

in this way you will get all elements of the `ListFragment` spaced by `5 dip`

Answer (score 0):

ListViews (along with Fragments, ListFragments, etc) appear to override the provided layout's root parameters (height, width), in order to fit the predefined View/Item dimensions into the parent. This also seems to happen with each of the layout's children Maximum dimensions, for instance, the TextView from AOSP's simple_list_item_1.xml

Since you are asking specifically for ListView item spacing, I would still not use dividerHeight as suggested by blackbelt, as this would change the centering of your original content (also the first item would not have the desired spacing from the top of the list, as the divider is below each item).

For ListView items, you can generally override this behavior by setting a custom layout (called by a custom adapter) with a top and bottom **margin**. See the following sample based simple_list_item_1.xml and note the margin modifiers at the end:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"

    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
/>
```

(you might need to provide inline values for non-public references to "?android:attr")

You would then have to call a custom adapter for your list (such as ArrayAdapter) and supply it with your custom list item XML.

Comment: as a hack you can also try to reset the LayoutParams on execution (programatically) on the adapter's getView method. ListViews, Fragments and ListFragments behave very randomly depending if you are using compatibility or stack libraries, so I am suggesting this as an alternative.